# Microsoft Dynamics 365 organizationName exception

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to get the list of organizations from a server using this code:

```
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
var discoveryUri = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc", "10.20.30.40"));
var discoveryServiceProxy = new DiscoveryServiceProxy(discoveryUri, null, clientCredentials, null);
discoveryServiceProxy.Authenticate();
var retrieveOrganizationResponse = (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)discoveryServiceProxy.Execute(new RetrieveOrganizationRequest());
```

but in the last line throws this error:

organizationName

the Exception type is this:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Discovery/IDiscoveryService/ExecuteDiscoveryServiceFaultFault

Please your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be to do with how your are forming the `new RetrieveOrganizationRequest()` - specifically, that your don't supply any arguments.

There is an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328180.aspx), that shows how to get the list of organizations from the Discovery Service.

```
// Retrieve details about all organizations discoverable via the
// Discovery service.
RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgsRequest =
    new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest()
    {
        AccessType = EndpointAccessType.Default,
        Release = OrganizationRelease.Current
    };
RetrieveOrganizationsResponse organizations =
    (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)service.Execute(orgsRequest);

// Print each organization's friendly name, unique name and URLs
// for each of its endpoints.
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Retrieving details of each organization:");
foreach (OrganizationDetail organization in organizations.Details)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Organization Name: {0}", organization.FriendlyName);
    Console.WriteLine("Unique Name: {0}", organization.UniqueName);
    Console.WriteLine("Endpoints:");
    foreach (var endpoint in organization.Endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Name: {0}", endpoint.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("  URL: {0}", endpoint.Value);
    }
}
```